# Typeahead not displaying background for answers

Tags: typeahead.js

I'm trying to use typeahead.js and I'm getting some strange results in the dropdown.
[image]

Notice I've typed in bob and I have several results, the first one of which is above the input box and they all have no background. Anyone know what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using Bootstrap? It looks like you are missing necessary CSS styles.

https://github.com/jharding/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css

Comment: Thanks, working better now, but it still has one problem. The first result is still repeated over top of the box like it's doing in the picture.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help without seeing the actual HTML/CSS. Maybe HTML or some extra CSS is mixing things up.